# Как в Celery извлечь результаты завершённых задач из backend[redis]?

Tags: python, django, celery

Если подключить в flower свой проект, то там можно посмотреть по адресу localhost:5555/task/ полные данные о задаче (выполняемой, завершённой). Как получить все эти данные через python код без flower? В качестве backend используется redis.
Пробовал согласоно [оф.туториалу](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html?#django-celery-results-using-the-django-orm-cache-as-a-result-backend) подключить модуль django-celery-results. При использовании следующего кода:

```
from django_celery_results.models import TaskResult
print TaskResult.objects.all()
```

Получаю

```
<QuerySet []>
```

Настройки settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...

    # celery results
    'django_celery_results',

    ...
]

REDIS_URL = 'redis://localhost'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = REDIS_URL
```

Redis работает, что подтверждает и сам flower (есть возожность посмотреть задачи) и redis-cli:

```
>redis-cli ping
>PONG
```

**UPD1**: Поскольку работа идёт с бакэндом - решил запрашивать завершённые задачи непосредственно из неё. Код принял следующий вид:

```
import redis
from celery import result

r = redis.Redis("localhost", 6379)
t = r.keys(pattern="celery-task-meta*")
for i in t:
    y = i[17:]
    res = result.AsyncResult(y)
    print "{0} {1}".format(res, res.status)
```

Получаю результат вида

```
7b3d6735-fdaf-4511-a77d-e814393db786 SUCCESS
2c413ffc-342e-4aa4-ba5c-e019035d0caa FAILURE
35539d7b-fa44-4b3f-a10f-8b6d001448b2 FAILURE
```

Так же могу обратиться к свойству "Traceback", чтобы узнать причину ошибки. Но теперь я не знаю имени, которая стоит за конкретным id. Да и данных во flower гораздо больше.
**UPD2** Есть некий класс [celery.worker.request](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.worker.request.html), у которого есть куча свойств и по документации данный класс позволяет "*class, that specifies how tasks are executed.*". Согласно документации у класса есть много свойств, которые мне в общем-то и нужны. Но не могу понять как добраться до этих свойств.
**UPD3** Класс, на который я наткнулся только для задач, которые выполняются на текущий момент и не даёт доступ к задачам, которые уже отработали

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть плагин [django-celery-monitor](https://djangopackages.org/packages/p/django-celery-monitor/), который добавляет в админку искомый функционал. Данный плагин заносит в новую таблицу базы данных результаты задач и другие параметры. Делает он это при помощи дополнительно запускаемого монитора активности celery (так называемая камера\camera). Плагин достаточно легко модифицируется. Так же плагин позволяет фильтровать результаты и запускать выбранные задачи.
Плагин крайне удобный, но до конца он не решает мою конкретную задачу. По карйней мере в нём можно посмотреть как реализовать задуманное. Если кого не смущает размещение раздела о задачах в админке - смело используйте.
Так же стоит упомянуть flower - автору не удалось разобраться в механизме работы данного плагина (попросту не хватает знаний и опыта), но отдельно запущенный веб-сервер - не очень изящное решение в рамках комплексного проекта.

Comment: Собственно свою задачу получилось реализовать достаточно просто. В своём проекте создал модель, ссылающаюся на таблицы, которые создаются данным приложением. Далее просто вывел их отображение на страницу.